# How to pass a string variable with spaces to a shell script in cpp program

Tags: c++, shell, sh

I am trying to send a string variable which has contents with spaces to a shell script from a cpp program. But the parameters I am receiving in the shell script is delimited by spaces. Can someone help me with sending and receiving the entire string as it is.

My Cpp program

```
spectrix% cat t.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string cstmrAdrs = "ECit Jlrd blr KA";
string cmd = "/home/user/siteCheck/t.sh " + cstmrAdrs;
int ret = system(cmd.c_str());
cout << "ret = " << ret;
return 0;
}
```

My Shell script

```
spectrix% cat t.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
echo $4
spectrix%


spectrix% CC t.cpp
spectrix% ./a.out
ECit
Jlrd
blr
KA
ret = 0
```

How can I get the string passed as entire content of $1.

Comment: Enclosed in quotes would be my guess. As in `string cstmrAdrs = "\"ECit Jlrd blr KA\"";`

Comment: Actually the 'cstmrAdrs' is coming from the frontend.

Comment: So you implement a bit of string manipulation to set up another string variable that contains the value of `cstmrAdrs` surrounded by quotes. Details are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Use Boost.Process or another library that lets you pass each argument as a separate argument instead of relying on shell parsing. (Fork+exec if you want to do it manually)

Answer (score 0):

For a "sh-like" shell,

1. Replace every single-quotes (`'`) with `'\''`.
2. Encapsulate the result in single-quotes.

For example,

- `abc def` becomes `'abc def'`.
- `ikegami's answer` becomes `'ikegami'\''s answer'`.

Notes:

- You'd need to escape for `cmd` in Windows.
- Arguments starting with `-` can cause trouble.
- `+` is also accepted as an option prefix by some programs.
- Arguments containing the NUL character can't be passed.

Comment: Probably a better fix is to pass the arguments to `execvp` as an array; then you bypass the shell, and thus the need to escape or quote anything from the shell.

Comment: @tripleee, You could, but that involves creating a pipe and using fork in addition.